# Post input type text from bootstrap navbar to codeigniter controller

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, post, bootstrap-4, codeigniter-3

I have this code

```
                <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                    <?php echo form_open('users/modificaAzienda2'); ?>
                    <input type="hidden" name="usernameHidden" id="usernameHidden" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
                    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Cerca Azienda" aria-label="Search" id="completaAziende" name="completaAziende">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Cerca</button>
                    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
                </form>
```

[image]

When I put something and submit the post request does not go to ('users/modificaAzienda2') instead it goes to a different url as shown in the below image :

[image]

Now, if the code is without the form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0"

all data is posted and the controller opens the correct view :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must not have a form within a form: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element

But you do that, because Codeigniter's `echo form_open()` creates a form tag - see [form_open()](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html#form_open) - which you locate within your parent `<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">`. The second form will be ignored.

Resolve it with adding the classes as attributes to `echo form_open()`:

```
$attr = array('class' => 'form-inline my-2 my-lg-0');
echo form_open('users/modificaAzienda2', $attr);
//....
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```